# Using ExtJS with Browserify

Tags: extjs, browserify

Anybody with experience using Browserify to manage ExtJS components? I cannot seem to find any examples around.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean with "to manage ExtJS components"? perhaps this could be done with the framework itself.

Comment: Given I got almost all other libraries such as jquery, moment, handlebars in browserify, I will also like to browserify ExtJS. Although, there is no problem using them seperately.

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you talking about?

Comment: I'm having ExtJS 3.4 in mind